# PHP: strpos & substr with UTF-8

Tags: php, utf-8, strpos

Say I have a long UTF-8 encoded string.

And say I want to detect if `$var` exists in this string.

Assuming `$var` is always going to be simple letters or numbers of ascii characters (e.g. `"hello123"`) I shouldn't need to use `mb_strpos` or `iconv_strpos` right? Because it doesn't matter if the position is not character-wise correct as long as its consistent with the other functions.

Example:

```
$var='hello123';
$pos=strpos($utf8string,$var);
if ($pos!==false) $uptohere=substr($ut8string,0,$pos);
```

Am I correct that the above code will extract everything up to `'hello123'` regardless of whether the string contains fancy UTF-8 characters? My logic is that because both `strpos` and `substr` will be consistent with each other (even if this is consistently wrong) then it should still work.

Comment: Surely it doesn't matter because `substr` will think exactly the same and so it will crop the string still at the correct point?

Comment: ASCII being UTF8 compatible, I do believe it should work. But why don't you just try with a few Chinese / Japanese strings?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. There's no ambiguity about the characters themselves, i.e. `hello123` can't possibly anything else in UTF-8. The way you're slicing it, it doesn't matter whether you're slicing by character or by byte number.

So yes, this is safe, **as long as your string is UTF-8 and thereby ASCII compatible**.

See here for quick test: http://3v4l.org/XnM8s

Why this works:

The string "漢字hello123" in UTF-8 looks like this as bytes (I hope this aligns correctly):

```
e6 | bc | a2 | e5 | ad | 97 | 68 | 65 | 6c | 6c | 6f | 31 | 32 | 33
     漢      |      字      | h  | e  | l  | l  | o  | 1  | 2  | 3
```

`strpos` will look for the byte sequence `68656c6c6f313233`, returning `6` as the starting byte of "hello123". `substr` will slice 6 bytes from byte `0`, returning "漢字". There is no ambiguity. You're finding and slicing by bytes, it doesn't matter how many characters there are.

You need to either work entirely in *characters*, in which case the string functions must be encoding aware. Or you work entirely in *bytes*, in which case the only requirement is that bytes aren't ambiguous (say "hello123" could match "中国" encoded in BIG5, because the bytes are the same (they don't, just an example)). UTF-8 is *self-synchronizing*, meaning there's no such ambiguity.

Comment: I always get confused which way the utf8 and ascii compatibility goes ;-) I figured that ascii is utf8 compatible.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, it is very helpful. Still though, if the string was not UTF-8, say it was 10 chars, and `strlen` thought it was 20 chars, then strpos might find my `$var` at 12, then `substr` would still cut it at the correct place..? Please explain why this isn't the case if it isn't.

Comment: @Jack "Compatible" in the sense that an ASCII string (e.g. `hello123`) can't be mistaken for some other string. I'm just making this example up because I don't know of a working example off the top of my head, but `hello123` in ASCII may match the string `中国` in BIG5.

Comment: @Alasdair Not sure what you're trying to ask, see update for more explanation though. :)

Comment: "_You're finding and slicing by bytes, it doesn't matter how many characters there are._" This means that the needle can also be utf-8? If I try to search "字hello123" I think we can apply the same reasoning that you did... there is a risk of corrupting the string?

Answer (score 4):

In UTF-8 you must use mb_* functions, in your case you need replace substr to

```
mb_substr($var, 0, N, 'UTF-8');
```

[mb_substr()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr.php)